# jsTree Selecte most nested node

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jstree

Greetings,
I just started to use jsTree and I have a question for you guys.
How can I select only the most nested node - the node which doesn't
have any children. additionally, when this node is selected, I would
like to submit my form which contains the jsTree. How can I then
access selected node?

Comment: What if there is more than one node with no children?

Comment: then I should choose one from x available

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to grab the nodes with jQuery:

```
myTree.find('li').has(':not(ul)');
```